# How do I cap a number to keep it below a certain cap number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am working on my 5th JavaScript project, which is an RPG-esque battle.  The player starts out with 20 health points and 1 potion that restores 5 health.  Everything works smoothly, except for the fact that if you use the potion at full health(20), your health goes to 25.  I want to cap it to make the player's max health 20, so that if you use a potion at full health, it does nothing, or if you use it at, say, 16 health, it restores to 20, and not 21.  I have looked into the `Math.min`/`Math.max` methods, and the use of them with `parseInt` to create a min/max limit, but when I integrated it into my code, it didn't work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.min()`, like this:

```
var health = 16;
var potion = 5;

health = Math.min(20, health + potion)
```

It might be a bit counter-intuitive, but you use `Math.min()` for a "max" cap, and `Math.max()` for a "min" cap.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answers(well, at least one), but I had a friend point out a very simple solution, which made me feel a little bit stupid.

```
var itemSelection = prompt("HP: " + playerHp + "\nItems:\n1.Potion - INFO: Restores 5 HP.  Can attack after use" + "\nQTY: " + potions + "\n2.Exit");

switch (itemSelection) {
    case '1':
        if(playerHp === 20){
            alert("You are already at full health.");
        }else{
        playerHp += 5;
        potions -= 1;
        if (playerHp > 20) {
            playerHp = 20;
        }
        }
        playerTurn();
        break;
    case '2':
        playerTurn();
        break;
    default:
        alert("Invalid choice.");
        itemMenu();
}
```